# Problem with BURG in elementary OS Freya

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

I have dual boot my computer with Windows 10 and elementary OS Freya, I Follow this step: [Tweak your startup with this nice elementary-styled bootloader theme](http://elementaryosandmore.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/tweak-your-startup-with-this-nice.html) I type the command in the terminal and work fine

with the sudo burg-install "(hd0)" I get:

```
 Installation finished. No error reported.
```

and in the tutorial said: Congrats, you now have BURG installed on your computer! Go check it out by rebooting your pc! If you want the awesome elementary-ish theme, read further!

I Installed that theme moving the files for the folder with root privilegies but when I reboot my computer nothing happen I press "T" (like said in the blog) for select the theme and nothing happen, press F3 for the resolution and nothing happen, why?

Comment: ...maybe because this tutorial is more than 2 years old?

Comment: @Rafael in the comments have a question from the 2015 http://elementaryosandmore.blogspot.com/2013/06/tweak-your-startup-with-this-nice.html?showComment=1429960963893#c8272891280159782323 and the reply was "Yes"

Comment: What means "nothing happens" ? black screen or default grub or elementary OS logo ?

Comment: @Ravan the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `fdisk -l` output [here](https://i.imgur.com/Zwq6Fnn.png)

You have to replace (hd0) with **(hd1)**

To customize ,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Open `grub-customizer` then you will see a prompt like this :Click on "yes"

[image: Imgur]

Now under `List Configuration` --> Right click on the entries you want to hide and click `Remove`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `sudo burg-emu` and change the theme and resolution from there.

I found this nice tutorial for Ubuntu 14.04, so it should work great with Freya: http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/ubuntu/brug-and-theme-configuration.html

Comment: I try but still getting the default